# child not stretching to its parent

Tags: html, css, position, parent-child

I am not sure why contactBox is overlapping the mainInfo box.The contact box is also not stretching to its parent container which is 960px.

CSS

```
.mainInfo {
position:relative;
height:500px;
background-color: pink;
padding:30px 0 0 30px;

}

.col-6 .imagePlaceholder {
width:300px;
height:420px;
background-color: red;
}

.col-6 .about {
position: absolute;
top:30px;
left:414px;
padding:1em;
}

.contactBox {
height:450px;
background-color:green;
}
```

Here is a JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2zm47/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably code this css differently, but checkout the

```
.mainInfo {
position:relative;
height:500px;
background-color: pink;
padding:30px 0 0 30px;

}

.col-6 .imagePlaceholder {
width:300px;
height:420px;
background-color: red;
}

.col-6 .about {
position: absolute;
top:30px;
left:414px;
padding:1em;
}

.contactBox {
height:450px;
background-color:green;
}
```

I hope this helps. I put a note in the JS section of the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/emersive/84WeT/1/

Comment: ohhh right, thanks :) how would you code the CSS? would you use positioning?

Comment: As a general rule you should avoid absolute positioning. It definitely has its uses. I might first start by simplifying your html to follow the structure in which your want your site to flow more closely. If you want to have content side by side the better way to do it is with floats. This will help you if you want to make the site responsive later. Which it kind of looks like you are thinking about doing. Then, I would use floats, floats are really important to get the correct layout. In a couple years we can use flexbox and stuff.

http://jsfiddle.net/emersive/84WeT/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is messed up. Should be like:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="mainInfo">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="imagePlaceholder"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="about">
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

   <div class="contactBox"></div>
</div>
```